# geom_boxplot with mapped, variable widths per bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, geom

I would like to be able to *map* the width of each of the boxplots in a plot to a variable, or otherwise specify it.  Let's say I want the relative widths of the boxes in the figure below to be 1, 2, 3. Setting `varwidth` won't help me since the actual numbers of observations are the same for each bar.

I have the beginnings of a horrible hacky solution I can post, but would welcome something actually good!

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(101) 
dd <- data.frame(f = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 10)),
                 y = rnorm(30))
g1 <- ggplot(dd, aes(f,y)) + geom_boxplot()
print(g1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My basic idea (which would take more work to make it nice) is to `ggplot_build()`; hack the relevant elements in the data for the layer; and redraw the plot: example below.  Obviously not as nice as having a real mapping/scaling system but maybe OK for simple cases ...

```r
rel_wid <- c(1, 2, 3)
g1B <- ggplot_build(g1)
newdat <- g1B$data[[1]]
wids <- mean(newdat$new_width)*rel_wid/mean(rel_wid)
newdat <- within(newdat,
{
    xmin <- newx - wids/2
    xmax <- newx + wids/2
})
g2 <- g1B
g2$data[[1]] <- newdat
library(grid)
grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(g2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit more concise and does it all in one gulp, without having to build the plot first:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(101) 
dd <- data.frame(f = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 10)), y = rnorm(30))

ggplot(dd, aes(f,y)) + 
  Map(\(a, b) geom_boxplot(data = a, width = b), split(dd, dd$f), 1:3 * 0.35)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>